# Can't start Compute engine after upgrading from Free Trial

Tags: google-compute-engine

I used GCP on a Free Trial for a couple of month and set up and a Compute engine VM, when the Trial budget ended the VM went down and I can't restart it even after upgrading to monthly payments.

Every time I want to restart the VM i get this error:

> The default network interface [nic0] is frozen.

I tried to create a new VM, but also got an error:

> Google Compute Engine is not ready for use yet in the project. It may take several minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine in the project.

Created a new service account and played with roles, but the result is still the same.

What should I do in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, Ivan

Answer (score 1):

This issue looks like a known [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/%22The$20default$20network$20interface$20[nic0]$20is$20frozen%22$20%7Csort:relevance/gce-discussion/25YgtMktgr0/uHKhSI0TBAAJ) from Google side:

Workaround: 
1. Try creating a new VPC network using the following:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/create

Now create a VM instance using the new network

2. Create a new project under the same billing account and try creating VM using the default network